# Can I permanently lock a MySQL table to prevent inserts

Tags: mysql

I have a complicated situation where I would like to prevent inserts into a MySQL table, but keep it open for edits/updates to existing data. Can this be done? I've searched around here, but could not find a similar situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a before insert trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT
   ON table_name FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '99999'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You cannot insert rows to this table.';
END;
```

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER no_more_work_orders BEFORE INSERT ON work_orders FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '99999' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You can no longer use this system to create work orders.'; END;
Caused the following error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SQLSTATE VALUE '99999' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You can no longer use this' at line 5

Comment: Anyone reading this needs to add `DELIMTER` to make this work. After which it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Use a before insert trigger to set the new values back to the old ones? Or, even better, set it to do nothing at all - as per below. As Eric Raymond pointed out in his (good) book "The Art of Unix Programming", the fastest code is that which doesn't have to run at all!. (Note - don't have a running system to test - but I think the underlying concept is pretty clear!).

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE TRIGGER blank_insert BEFORE INSERT ON test1
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    ;
  END;
$

DELIMITER ;
```

Perhaps an even more elegant way would be to do what's outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861564/make-a-single-table-in-mysql-read-only) - i.e. set PRIVILEGES to UPDATE and SELECT only for your users on your table?